# Getting php data from jQuery ajax without html forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, single-page-application

My idea is to write single page web application using jQuery and having server side in php, I want to do it without using html forms. So far I have this new.php file:

```
<?php
     echo "Welcome";
 ?>
```

And javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/pmfServer/new.php',

    success: function (data) {
        alert('success' + data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  

            alert("Something went wrong " + errorThrown);

    }
});
});
```

The alert i get is just "success" with nothing else.
I have apache web server running, and when i type same url in web browser it says "welcome".

Is this proper way to do server side since I'm not going to use forms? 
Do I have to use some frameworks for that?

Comment: is the first block, `new.php`??

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I edited.

Comment: The code itself is fine, is that definitely the path to the file?

Comment: When I type the same URL in web browser it shows me "welcome" message.

Comment: Try to look at the browser's network inspector so you can see what data is being transmitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/pmfServer/new.php'
    }).done(function(response){
        var response = $.trim(response);
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

If you still get no reply from ajax, please verify your path (url: '....')

Also check your console for any errors...

One last thing: Ajax files should not always be accessible directly from browsers... You may want to consider protecting them (while they will still be reachable by xmlhttprequest:

```
<?php

//protect the file from un-auth access
define('AJAX_REQUEST', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!AJAX_REQUEST) {die();}

echo "Welcome";

?>
```

Of course in your particular "Welcome" case, that might not be necessary... I am just referring to more "sensitive" ajax files ;)

Answer (score 0):

Old functions that I've did allows you to make a AJAX request to an URL also.

```
function Get(t,e,n){!function(){var s=new XMLHttpRequest;s.onreadystatechange=function(){4==s.readyState&&200==s.status?(e(s.responseText),s=void 0):s.status>=500&&(s=void 0,n(0))},t+=t.indexOf("?")>-1?"&tsmp="+Date.now():"?tsmp="+Date.now(),s.open("GET",t,!0),s.send()}()}
function Post(t,e,n,o){!function(){var s=new XMLHttpRequest;s.onreadystatechange=function(){4==s.readyState&&200==s.status?(n(s.responseText),s=void 0):s.status>=500&&(s=void 0,o(0))},t+=t.indexOf("?")>-1?"&tsmp="+Date.now():"?tsmp="+Date.now(),s.open("POST",t,!0),s.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),s.send(e)}()}
```

This is very simple to use... if you want to across the jQuery:

```
Get("http://localhost/pmfServer/new.php",function(msg){alert(msg)},function(err){alert("Error")})
```

This is to post data and after get:

```
Post("http://example.com/yourtext.php","wow=1",function(msg){alert(msg)},function(err){alert("Error")})
```

Also see if there are no errors in the console.
And... I recommend you to use `encodeURIComponent` when sending some string with user data.
`encodeURIComponent("ÃÃO.. ! @ # $ % Ohh! & %><")`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .html file beside the .php and change the url in javascript code to "new.php" as the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'new.php',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success' + data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
            alert("Something went wrong " + errorThrown);
    }
});
});
```

I suggest to use framework for single page application such as http://durandaljs.com/